# Fragment incide AppCompatDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialog

I have simple DialogWindow
XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
class DialogWindowBuyingStock(context: Context, private val viewModel: MainViewModel, private val stock: Stock) : AppCompatDialog(context) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.buy_stock_dialogwindow)
    }
}
```

In which i have some fragments for example the Main one:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: MainFragmentBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[MainFragmentViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        main_buy_button.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_buyFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

It works perfectly for the first time i start Dialog Window, but when i close it and start again, i got this **llegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #20: Duplicate id 0x7f080136, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment**
How can i fix that?